# Find all lines using regular expression

Tags: regex

There is a text like this (many lines)

```
1. sdfsdf werwe werwemax45 rwrwerwr
2. 34348878 max max44444445666 sdf
3. 4353424 23423eedf max55 dfdg dfgdf
4. max45
5. 4324234234sdfsdf maxx34534
```

Using regular expressions I need to find all lines and include a word `max<digits>` (containing digits instead of literally `<digits>`) into a matching group.

So I've tried this regular expression:

```
^.*?\b(max\d+)\b.*?$
```

But it finds only lines containing `max...` and ignores others.

Then I’ve tried

```
^.*?\b(max\d+)?\b.*?$
```

It finds all lines but without matching group containing `max...`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, [^.*?\b(max\d+)\b.*$|.*](https://regex101.com/r/tOJvG9/1) should work.

Comment: @SebastianProske This additionally matches an empty string between the last character of a line and the line-break.

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly.
I modified you regex a bit and it works.
Thank you very much

^.*?\b(max\d+)\b.*$|^.*$

Comment: `^.*\b(max\d+)\b.*|.+$` should work, actually.

Comment: No need for alternations. Use grouping constructs correctly.

Comment: Please avoid answering in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be "debugged" with a slightly modified pattern, [`^(.*?)\b(max\d+)?\b(.*?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/MiB6L2/1), with the rest of the pattern wrapped into separate capturing groups. You can see that the lines are all matched by the Group 3 pattern, the last `.*?`. It happens because the first `.*?` is skipped (since it is a lazy pattern), then `(max\d=)?` matches an empty string at the start of the line (none begins with `max` + digits - but if any line starts with that pattern, [you would get it captured](https://regex101.com/r/MiB6L2/2)), and the last `.*?` captures the whole line.

You can fix it by wrapping the first part into a non-capturing optional group capturing the `max\d+` into an *obligatory* capturing group

```
^(?:.*?\b(max\d+)\b)?.*?$
```

Or even without `?$` at the end since `.*` will match greedily up to the end of the line:

```
^(?:.*?\b(max\d+)\b)?.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MiB6L2/4)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (with `m` option, start of a line)
- `(?:.*?\b(max\d+)\b)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(max\d+)` -  Group 1 (obligatory, will be tried once): `max` and 1+ digits
  - `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - rest of the line